# How can I mark a stage as FAILED but continue its execution in Jenkins?

Tags: jenkins, groovy, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-plugins

Here's my code, it uses jenkins-plugin:

```
pipeline
{
    agent any
    stages
    {
        stage ('Run Demos')
        {
            def demoPath = '"' + env.WORKSPACE + 'MyDemo.exe"'
            def demoNames = ["demo1", "demo2"]
            for (demoName in demoNames)
            {
                bat('start /b /wait "" ' + demoPath + ' ' + demoName)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

When `bat('start /b /wait "" ' + demoPath + ' ' + demoName)` fails inside the loop, the whole stage is stopped. I can workaround this by adding a `try-catch` or `catchError` block around the bat call, but then the step is marked as SUCCESS (green) even if the return code marks FAILURE (red).

Is there a way I can mark the stage as **FAILURE** on error and **NOT stop the execution** of the remaining demos?  I don't want to break each demo run into different stages.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In declarative pipelines, you can achieve this using the `catchError` block, like so:

```
stage ('Run Demos')
{
    steps 
    {
        def demoPath = '"' + env.WORKSPACE + 'MyDemo.exe"'
        def demoNames = ["demo1", "demo2"]
        for (demoName in demoNames)
        {
            catchError(buildResult: 'FAILURE', stageResult: 'FAILURE') 
            {
                bat('start /b /wait "" ' + demoPath + ' ' + demoName)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The overall build as well as the stage will be marked as **FAILURE** in case of exception, but the remaining demos and following stage **will execute regardless**.

Use `SUCCESS` or `null` to keep the `buildResult` from being set when an error is caught.

#### See also:

- [Pipeline: Basic Steps](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/workflow-basic-steps/)

Comment: Your catchError block should move into the loop. Otherwise, it will exit the loop and continue running.

Comment: @ycr I've updated my answer, thank you. This is more appropriate given the context of the problem

Answer (score 1):

Another option is to use `currentBuild.result` to set the status in the catch block.

```
script {
    for (demoName in demoNames) {
        try {
            bat('start /b /wait "" ' + demoPath + ' ' + demoName)
        } catch (e) {
            currentBuild.result = 'FAILURE'
            unstable("One of the demos failed")
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Does this solution mark the respective stage as FAILED as well or only the current build?

Comment: @Pexers I updated the answer slightly. Now the stage will be marked as unstable and the build will be marked as failed.